# Delegating targets to other make files, in parallel, without include

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have a `Makefile`:

```
foo: T = a b c
bar: T = d e f

foo bar:
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.other $(T)
```

This does the wrong thing on `make -j foo bar` if `Makefile.other` encodes dependency information between a b c and d e f.  Is there a way to make it do the "right" thing?  That is, in all cases, only execute the `$(MAKE) -f ...` once, and invoke if with `a b c` if I `make foo`, with `d e f` if I `make bar`, and with `a b c d e f` if I `make foo bar`?

I can't use `include`, because `Makefile.other` is autogenerated by a tool that I use, and itself includes generated files, and makes the `clean` target too slow.  I've tried `T +=` instead of `T =`, and making `foo` and `bar` depend on a separate target with the rule, but `T` is rule-local, and so the other target only sees the info from one of them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "concatenate the list of T's".  If you just want one list then declare `T = a b c d e f` and don't use target-specific variables.  But I assume you don't want to do that because you want to run only some targets when you invoke `make foo` and the other targets when you invoke `make bar`.  So in what way does it work to "concatenate the list"?

Comment: I've reworded that paragraph.  Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `make foo bar` make will *always* run both the targets `foo` and `bar`, so it will always run the `$(MAKE) ...` recipe twice: once for `foo` and once for `bar`.  You can't have it run just one recipe when you run `make foo bar`.

So, I can tell you how to set `T` to the right values depending on which targets are being built, but that won't help since the sub-make is always run twice regardless.  *That's* the part that's tricky.

If you really, really want to do this you could do something like this:

```
SUBMAKE = $(MAKE) -f Makefile.other $(T)

T :=
ifeq ($(filter foo,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),foo)
    T += a b c
endif
ifeq ($(filter bar,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),bar)
    T += d e f
endif

foo bar:
        +$(SUBMAKE)$(eval SUBMAKE :=)
```

What does this do?  First, it computes `T` based on the values on the command line (which are stored in `MAKECMDGOALS`.

Second, in the recipe it first expands to the value of `SUBMAKE`, then uses the `eval` function to set `SUBMAKE` to empty.  This means that the first time this recipe is run it will invoke the submake, but all subsequent times that variable is empty so it does nothing.

It ain't so pretty, and I'm not really sure it will do what you really want, but it does what you asked for.

Comment: Or, of course, you can use Mike's method which is a lot more "make-like".

Comment: What does the `+` in `+$(SUBMAKE)` do?  Also, if instead of this, `foo` and `bar` were both made to depend on a `submake` rule, then it would only be invoked once, because after that make thinks it's up to date, right?  (As long as it's not a :: rule, that is?)

Anyway, neat trick with MAKECMDGOALS; thanks!

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html for info on `+`.  If `foo` and `bar` both depended on another rule then that rule would be run only once, but the rules for `foo` and `bar` would still be invoked.  If those targets had no recipe then they wouldn't do anything, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do what you want with just the targets `foo` and `bar`.

You are asking for `make foo bar` to do something other than *make* `foo` *and make* `bar`.

The rule:

```
foo bar:
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.other $(T)
```

is just shorthand for:

```
foo :
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.other $(T)

bar:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.other $(T)
```

So, for illustration, if `Makefile.other` is:

```
.phony: a b c d e f

a b c d e f:
    @echo $@
```

Then `make foo bar` cannot have any outcome but:

```
$ make foo bar
make -f Makefile.other a b c
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/imk/develop/SO/scrap'
a
b
c
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/imk/develop/SO/scrap'
make -f Makefile.other d e f
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/imk/develop/SO/scrap'
d
e
f
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/imk/develop/SO/scrap'
```

`make` makes `foo`, then makes `bar`, as per orders. This *is* "the right thing".

If you want to make `a b c d e f`, then you have to define a
*third* `make` target that requires all of them to be made. For example:

```
foo_todo = a b c
bar_todo = d e f
foobar_todo = $(foo_todo) $(bar_todo)

foo bar foobar:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.other $($@_todo)
```

Then `make foo` `make bar` and `make foo bar` all behave as before,
and `make foobar` outputs:

```
make -f Makefile.other a b c d e f
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/imk/develop/SO/scrap'
a
b
c
d
e
f
```